# How To Disable Cookies in apache camel

Tags: cookies, apache-camel

I have tried to disable cookies in camel with below code snippet

```
httpClient.cookiePolicy=ignoreCookies
```

(given in apache camel documentation)

But cookies are still not ignored. Do we need any more configurations to disable the cookies ?

Any help can be appreciated on this.